# IronPython reloading modules (UMD, runfile)

Tags: python, module, iron

I'm working on some code with IronPython 2.7.0.40 on .NET 4.0.30319.18444.  While in the IronPython console, if I make any changes to my modules, they will not take affect (unless I close, open a new console, switch back into the proper directory and reload the modules).  Is there a way to make IronPython see the changes?  In "normal" Python I'd use "runfile" which automatically reloads modules and sees any recent changes to the source, but seems like that's not available here in IronPython so I'm using execfile() which keeps using the initial version of my modules, ignoring changes.

Answer (score 2):

Just found out there is a function "reload" to do this.  Unfortunately you have to manually call it for each module that has changed:

```
>>> reload(Module1)
>>> reload(Module2)
...
```

Comment: +1 Just had the same issue, you should mark this as the answer as it solves the problem. One remark: I'm not using a console but embedding Python. To reload a script I also clear the scope so before calling reload(mod) I also had to import(mod) again to get mod back into scrope. For future reference, I used the code `foreach( var mod in py.GetModuleFilenames() ) { py.Execute( String.Format( "import {0}; reload({0})", mod ), scope ) ); }`